# Using MFC, posting variable to thread along with message

Tags: c++, multithreading, casting, mfc

I am using `CWinThread`. And I have made the main GUI send to the thread an array in `LPARAM`. Example, this code **WORKS**:

```
//On GUI
char *headData = "L1";
PostThreadMessage(threadID,SEND_HEAD, 0, (LPARAM)head);
```

On the thread:

```
void CMyThread::OnSendhead( WPARAM, LPARAM lParam){
   char *head = (char*)lParam;
   if (strcmp(head,"L1")==0){
       //This line is reached.
   }
   return;
}
```

**But when I make a little change here:**

```
char *head = "L1"
unsigned char byteHead[3];
memcpy(byteHead, head, 3);
PostThreadMessage(threadID,SEND_HEAD, 0, (LPARAM)byteHead);
```

On the thread:

```
 void CMyThread::OnSendhead( WPARAM, LPARAM lParam){
   unsigned char* byteHead = (unsigned char*)lParam;
   char head[3];
   memcpy(head, byteHead,3);
   head[3] = '\0';
   if (strcmp(head,"L1")==0){
       //This line is nerver reached.
   }
   return;
}
```

The line inside `if` is not reach. I have moved the code on thread to GUI for testing (without casting to LPARAM), and everthing works. So I guess I can't cast between `lParam` and `unsigned char*`? Why, and how can I do this? Thank you guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PostMessage` doesn't process the message immediately, but leaves it for the message loop to pick up later. If the data pointed to by `lparam` has been destroyed in the meantime, it's going to fail.

In your first example, you're passing a string literal. String literals tend to stay valid for the full lifetime of the program, so this is OK.

In the second example, you're using a local variable that presumably gets destroyed soon after you do the `PostMessage`.

To make this work, use `SendMessage` instead; it gets processed immediately. Or use a variable that is guaranteed to be valid until the message is processed.

Comment: So, since I want to send the message to the thread, there is no way for me to use `SendMessage`,  because I must have the threadID to know where the messege will be sent. But for the variable, I read somewhere about letting the thread touch GUI's members is not a good practice?

Comment: @TrungNguyen I don't have any experience with multi-threaded Windows programs, it's such a landmine-filled area and I've successfully avoided it thus far. I can't really give you any reliable advice beyond what's in the answer.

Comment: thank you, your answer is correct, the variable has been out of scoop before the thread picking up message. I used memcpy to store the value to another variable and it works.

Answer (score 1):

With `PostMessage` or `PostThreadMessage` you should always use heap allocated memory to send data, as small as `bool` and in the message handler function you delete it. You can wrap a message in some `struct`, for example:

```
 struct MyMsg
    {
       int msgCode; // specific to you, and you know underlying datatype
       char buffer[1024]; // or have a `vector` or dynamic-array you'd manage
    };
```

**Sender:**

```
MyMsg* msg = new MyMsg;
msg->msgCode = 0x1; // It's a string
strcpy_s(msg->buffer, "abc");
PostThreadMessage(threadID,SEND_HEAD, 0, (LPARAM)msg);
```

**Receiver**:

```
void CMyThread::OnSendhead( WPARAM, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MyMsg* msg= (MyMsg*)lParam;
    // use msg
    delete msg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, nice use of struct. But is this memory leak, if the `msg ` in sender not deleted?

Comment: No. the receiver is deleting the memory. It's a single process. All threads of same process full share the memory. Since two threads have different call stacks, you cannot share one's stack memory to another thread (unless you use blocking call such as `SendMessage`). You may use some smart pointer in receiver to ensure memory is deleted. You may have memory pool also so that memory allocation/de-allocation can be reduced, for sender-receiver communication. Long way to go... ;)

Comment: There is no need to allocate anything that can be passed by value on the freestore. And the freestore is not the only way to prolong the lifetime of data (object lifetime really is what matters, not where it's stored). Objects with static storage duration would be another way. Besides, messages posted to a thread can get lost (so you **do** have a potential memory leak). And that isn't even touching the issue of passing CRT resources across module boundaries. Pretty dangerous advice, downvote-worthy.

Comment: For small types, yes they don't need heap allocation. But for messages such as string, it is required. `PostMessage` call will itself fail, and sender can delete memory - it won't fail if PM call succeeds. We need to derive technique for multiple CRT versions (say a class that allocated/deallocates memory, the class residing in one DLL). It's not dangerous. You've problem with my suggestions, I cannot help much.

Comment: `PostMessage` doesn't post a message to a thread. `PostThreadMessage` does (and the message can get **silently** dropped). You need to make up your mind: *"use heap allocated memory to send data, as small as bool"* - *"For small types, yes they don't need heap allocation."* Which one is it?

Comment: I've not seen PM or PTM to fail, ever, even for high performance server-grade applications. Yes, for small types we don't need heap memory, but for making things generic, `new` is advised, so that memory can be deleted unconditionally without finding if message was sent for small type or not. For instance, an array of `char[4]` is 4 bytes, but unsafe, but a `long long` of 8 byte is safe - you cannot reliably determine, and call (not call) `delete`.

Comment: You don't need stress on a system for messages posted to a thread to disappear. It's enough for the target thread running a modal loop ([Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553)). There's also no guessing involved, based on the data type size, whether or not to delete the data. The message defines the protocol.